# Accurate JSON text encoding detection

Tags: json

In RFC4627 a method for identifying the Unicode encoding when a BOM is not present was described. This relied on the first 2 characters in the JSON text to always be ASCII characters. But in RFC7159, the specification defines JSON text as "ws value ws"; implying that a single string value would also be valid. So the first character will be the opening quote, but then any Unicode character allowed in a string could follow. Considering that RFC7159 also discourages the use of a BOM; and no longer describes the procedure for detecting the encoding from the first 4 octets (bytes), how should one detect it? UTF-32 should still work correctly as described in RFC4627, because the first character is four bytes and should still be ASCII, but what about UTF-16? The second (2-byte) character might not contain a zero-byte to help identify the correct encoding.

Comment: Interesting question. Certainly, determining the Unicode Scheme is more challenging. For example, a single byte, whose ASCII value is a digit, is also a valid JSON: its a single digit number in UTF-8.  How about proposing a solution, and we can discuss your solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a proposal that will be reliable. Obviously one first check for a BOM just in case. Next check for UTF-32 - if the first 3 bytes are zero then it's UTF-32BE, else if the 3 bytes after the first is zeros, it's UTF-32LE. So far we should be able to rely on the test, but now comes the problem. To test for UTF-16, we still have to look at 4 bytes. If we could assume that the first 2 characters are always ASCII, then we test if the first and third bytes are zeros for UTF-16BE and the second and fourth for UTF-16LE. But if the second character can be non-ASCII, what then?

Comment: Would it help if I give you a headstart with an implementation in C++ for detecting the encoding? As far as I know you don't need the BOM detection - but I have one implemented in C++,  too.

Comment: Anything that would give reliable detection would help, thanks. It can be pseudocode too; I just need the steps for what to test for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

This answer has been written for JSON according [RFC 7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159) whose character encoding was allowed to use all unicode schemes (UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32), where UTF-8 was the "default".

The current [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259) restricts the character encoding to be only UTF-8, which is a reasonable constraint.

---

After taking a look at an implementation which I made a couple years ago, I can tell that it's possible to unambiguously detect the given Unicode Scheme from just *one* character, given the following assumptions:

- The input must be Unicode
- The first character must be ASCII
- There must be no BOM

Consider this:

Assuming the first character is a `"["` (0x5B) - an ASCII.
Then, we may get these byte patterns:

```
UTF_32LE:    5B 00 00 00  
UTF_32BE:    00 00 00 5B
UTF_16LE:    5B 00 xx xx
UTF_16BE:    00 5B xx xx
UTF_8:       5B xx xx xx
```

where "xx" is either `EOF` or any other byte.

We should also note, that according RFC7159, the shortest valid JSON can be just one character. That is, it can be possibly 1, 2 or 4 byte - depending of the Unicode Scheme.

So, if it helps, here is an implementation in C++:

```
namespace json {
    
    //
    //  Detect Encoding
    //
    // Tries to determine the Unicode encoding of the input starting at 
    // first. A BOM shall not be present (you might check with function 
    // json::unicode::detect_bom() whether there is a BOM, in which case 
    // you don't need to call this function when a BOM is present).
    //
    // Return values:
    // 
    //   json::unicode::UNICODE_ENCODING_UTF_8
    //   json::unicode::UNICODE_ENCODING_UTF_16LE
    //   json::unicode::UNICODE_ENCODING_UTF_16BE
    //   json::unicode::UNICODE_ENCODING_UTF_32LE
    //   json::unicode::UNICODE_ENCODING_UTF_32BE
    //
    //  -1:     unexpected EOF
    //  -2:     unknown encoding
    //
    // Note:
    // detect_encoding() requires to read ahead a few bytes in order to deter-
    // mine the encoding. In case of InputIterators, this has the consequences
    // that these iterators cannot be reused, for example for a parser.
    // Usually, this requires to reset the istreambuff, that is using the 
    // member functions pubseekpos() or pupseekoff() in order to reset the get 
    // pointer of the stream buffer to its initial position.
    // However, certain istreambuf implementations may not be able to set the    
    // stream pos at arbitrary positions. In this case, this method cannot be
    // used and other edjucated guesses to determine the encoding may be
    // needed.
    
    template <typename Iterator>    
    inline int 
    detect_encoding(Iterator first, Iterator last) 
    {
        // Assuming the input is Unicode!
        // Assuming first character is ASCII!
        
        // The first character must be an ASCII character, say a "[" (0x5B)
        
        // UTF_32LE:    5B 00 00 00
        // UTF_32BE:    00 00 00 5B
        // UTF_16LE:    5B 00 xx xx
        // UTF_16BE:    00 5B xx xx
        // UTF_8:       5B xx xx xx
        
        uint32_t c = 0xFFFFFF00;
        
        while (first != last) {
            uint32_t ascii;
            if (static_cast<uint8_t>(*first) == 0)
                ascii = 0; // zero byte
            else if (static_cast<uint8_t>(*first) < 0x80)
                ascii = 0x01;  // ascii byte
            else if (*first == EOF)
                break;
            else
                ascii = 0x02; // non-ascii byte, that is a lead or trail byte
            c = c << 8 | ascii;
            switch (c) {
                    // reading first byte
                case 0xFFFF0000:  // first byte was 0
                case 0xFFFF0001:  // first byte was ASCII
                    ++first;
                    continue;
                case 0xFFFF0002:
                    return -2;  // this is bogus
                    
                    // reading second byte
                case 0xFF000000:    // 00 00 
                    ++first;
                    continue;
                case 0xFF000001:    // 00 01
                    return json::unicode::UNICODE_ENCODING_UTF_16BE;
                case 0xFF000100:    // 01 00
                    ++first;
                    continue;
                case 0xFF000101:    // 01 01
                    return json::unicode::UNICODE_ENCODING_UTF_8;
                    
                    // reading third byte:    
                case 0x00000000:  // 00 00 00
                case 0x00010000:  // 01 00 00  
                    ++first;
                    continue;                    
                    //case 0x00000001:  // 00 00 01  bogus
                    //case 0x00000100:  // 00 01 00  na
                    //case 0x00000101:  // 00 01 01  na
                case 0x00010001:  // 01 00 01 
                    return json::unicode::UNICODE_ENCODING_UTF_16LE;
                    
                    // reading fourth byte    
                case 0x01000000:
                    return json::unicode::UNICODE_ENCODING_UTF_32LE;
                case 0x00000001:
                    return json::unicode::UNICODE_ENCODING_UTF_32BE;
                    
                default:
                    return -2;  // could not determine encoding, that is,
                                // assuming the first byte is an ASCII.
            } // switch
        }  // while 
            
        // premature EOF
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. My original code followed the procedure described 
in RFC4627 that looks at the first 4 bytes as follows: 
00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE,
00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE,
xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE,
xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE,
xx xx xx xx  UTF-8.

With RFC 7159 allowing a single string value, one could get something like 00 xx xx 00 or xx 00 00 xx as well when UTF-16 is used. So I just changed my as follows:

00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE,
xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE,
00 xx        UTF-16BE,
xx 00        UTF-16LE,
all else     UTF-8.

As far as I can see, your code should work as is.